# echo MySQL table to HTML table displaying text for null fields

Tags: php

I am echoing a MySQL table to HTML table, but some of my database fields are empty.  When a database field is empty, how can I specify an alternate text (rather than it just showing blank?

The following works perfect (with blank cells):

```
<?php
include("../config.php");
$link = mysqli_connect("$db_host" , "$db_user" , "$db_password" , "$db");
mysqli_select_db($link, $db);

$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM the_table");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Phone</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";    
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

I think the answer should look something like this (but it doesn't work):

```
if (empty($row['name'])) {
       echo "<td>Not Specified</td>"; 
    } else { 
       echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: try trimming if (empty(trim($row['name'])))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
if ($row['name'] == null) {
       echo "<td>Not Specified</td>"; 
    } else { 
       echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
}
```

Comment: and the answer given by Andre didn't worked? are you kidding me..:/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`if(empty($row['name']) || $row['name'] == "")`

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php for the empty documentation. Maybe your result contains spaces? Then use the trim function as commented on your question.